# Face Detection using Opencv : javacv class not found

Tags: java, php, jsp, opencv, javacv

**task workflow:**
Capture photo using webcam and save in a directory and load that image for opencv detection(face)

First time while running the program in Ubuntu,image is not getting saved and the exception occurs.

**error 1:**

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /var/cache/tomcat6/temp/javacpp8724578391270070/libjniopencv_core.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/cache/tomcat6/temp/javacpp8724578391270070/libopencv_core.so.2.4)
    java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1646)
    java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:787)
    java.lang.System.load(System.java:1022)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:566)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
    com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
    facerecognition.javafaces.TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:104)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /var/cache/tomcat6/temp/javacpp8724578391270070/libopencv_core.so.2.4: libtbb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1646)
    java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:787)
    java.lang.System.load(System.java:1022)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:566)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
    com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
    facerecognition.javafaces.TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:104)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.24 logs.

When the program runs for the second time then the image gets saves but the exception occurs

**error 2:**

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui
    facerecognition.javafaces.TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:104)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.24 logs.

I have used try catch,yet the exception comes.No issues when the program is running in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**error 1:**

libtbb.so is the Intel thread building blocks library, which you need to have installed.Since the other native libraries are being loaded, either you don not have tbb installed or it is not in your usr/lib folder.

**error 2:**
This is missing jar file error. Check if you have the javacv jar file included in your  runtime application classpath.